# Не появляется затемняющий фон под модальным окном

Tags: bootstrap

Взял пример с [сайта бутстрап](http://bootstrap-3.ru/). Все подключил. Модальное окно открывается, но не появляется затемняющий фон.
Код

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Посмотреть демо
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Название модали</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить изменения</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Почему нет серого фона?

Comment: укажите ссылку на ваш сайт, где можно наблюдать пролему

Comment: не могу, я пока на локальной машине делаю.